# ASP.NET MVC ActionResult method confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods, return-value, actionresult

In my ASP.NET MVC application I want to just update two variables in my Register method.

My register method in my controller looks like this(it hasn't got its own view, so im not sure what to return in this case):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Container c)
{

String email = c.register.Email.ToString();
String password = c.register.Password.ToString();
return view();
}
```

My index view looks like this;

```
@model VoterMvcTest.Models.Container    

@using(Html.BeginForm("Register", "Default1")) 
{
@Html.LabelFor(o => o.register.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(o => o.register.Email)
@Html.LabelFor(o => o.register.Password)
@Html.EditorFor(o => o.register.Password)
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

And my model looks like this;

```
public class Container
{
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public Register register { get; set; }

}

public class Login
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Register
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

When you click the button, I want the two variables email and password to be set, and available to use in another method. I'm not sure what I should return(The goal would be to stay in the same view). I've tried to redirect to the same view i'm currently at (index view), but it seems like that causes a postback and the variables are lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
ASP.NET MVC does not have ViewState as you would have when using WebForms. So if you 
perform a post and do not persist the data in either a database or a temporary memory 
(session object for instance) you'll lose that data as soon as the request has finished.
If you do some kind of validation and determine that the user was well registered you
could redirect him to another view using: 

    return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

Comment: yeah, I know, but I was just thinking if it was possible to somehow let the user login after the registration without redirecting him to another view(keep the login and registration in the same view). I haven't been bothered with making a database yet, just testing with some string variables.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you mean. Registration and Login are two different things. Did you look at the account cotroller when you create an internet app with MVC ? You have both actions with different views, they perform similar actions and then redirec the user to the index page. What you could do, using ajax, is an asynchronous process, and then registering/logging the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
return View("Index",c)
```

it will work